# How to set evil-mode to use evil-emacs-state-mode in new buffers?

Tags: evil

So far, I've tried this, but it doesn't see to be working - new buffers still start in normal mode. I'd prefer to default to evils emacs mode, and be able to switch into evil with C-z when I'm ready

```
(setq evil-emacs-state-modes (append evil-normal-state-modes evil-motion-state-modes))
(setq evil-normal-state-modes nil)
(setq evil-motion-state-modes nil)
```

Comment: Had some trouble finding the docs, EmacsWiki has a link http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil#toc5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `evil-default-state` to `emacs`.  The docstring reads:

> Documentation:
>
> The default state.
>
> This is the state a mode comes up in when it is not listed
>   in `evil-emacs-state-modes`, `evil-insert-state-modes` or
>   `evil-motion-state-modes`. The value may be one of `normal`,
>   `insert`, `visual`, `replace`, `operator`, `motion` and
>   `emacs`.

Hence: `(setq evil-default-state 'emacs)` should do it.