# automatically use evil for ibuffer and dired

Tags: evil, dired, ibuffer

I am switching from vim to emacs and have evil installed. Mostly evil runs perfectly, but after starting emacs the first time and running ibuffer or dired I have to turn on evil-mode (C-z). This is really annoying as I often restart Emacs and assume that I can use vim-Bindings when opening dired or ibuffer.

So how can I always have evil-mode turned on by default?

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10668/how-to-set-evil-mode-to-use-evil-emacs-state-mode-in-new-buffers) seemed to be leading to the right direction, but I could not get it working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few variables that determine the state in which Evil starts depending on the major-mode:

- `evil-emacs-state-modes` for major-modes coming up in emacs state
- `evil-insert-state-modes` for major-modes coming up in insert state

and so on. By default `ibuffer-mode` is part of `evil-emacs-state-modes`, which you should remove

```
(setq evil-emacs-state-modes (delq 'ibuffer-mode evil-emacs-state-modes))
```

`dired-mode` should not come up in emacs state by default, though, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Awesome! That did it! Maybe there are other things inside evil-emacs-state-modes, that could be removed... Whatever, thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Open your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), and put this in it:

```
(evil-mode t)
```

Now, every time Emacs is started, evil-mode will be turned on.

Comment: I already have that in my .emacs. Maybe I have to change some settings for ibuffer and dired? That would be a bad solution if I had to add settings for every new major-mode to make it startup in evil-mode, but at least it would be a solution. ;-)